# Newline character not working in FileContentResult, file text is one line

Tags: asp.net, .net, byte, newline, actionresult

For some reason the text below, once ran through the action below creates a straight line, instead of taking into account the `new line characters (\n)`.  Are they being stripped out with the `FileContentResult` or `GetBytes`, and if so can I fix this?

```
"<div id=\"exp-schedule-93943\" data-href=\"https://localhost:2222/widgets/v1/schedule?eventid=93943\" data-responsive=\"true\" data-protocol=\"https\" data-width=\"100%\" data-height=\"500px\"></div>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n   (function (d, s, id) {\n   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];\n   if (!d.getElementById(id)) {\n       js = d.createElement(s);\n       js.id = id;\n       js.async = true;\n       js.src = \"https://localhost:2222/scripts/exposure.widgets.min.js\";\n       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);\n   }\n   })(document, \"script\", \"exp.widgets\");\n</script>"
```

**Controller Action**

```
public virtual ActionResult Download(string text, string fileName)
        {
            var contentDisposition = new ContentDisposition
            {
                FileName = fileName,
                Inline = false,
            };

            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition.ToString());
            return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text), "text/plain");
        }
```

**Text.txt**

```
<div id="exp-events-19185" data-href="https://basketball.exposureevents.com/widgets/v1/events?organizationid=19185" data-css="https://cdn.exposureevents.com/content/external/bballshowcase.min.css" data-responsive="true" data-protocol="https" data-width="100%" data-height="500px"></div><script type="text/javascript">   (function (d, s, id) {   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];   if (!d.getElementById(id)) {       js = d.createElement(s);       js.id = id;       js.async = true;       js.src = "https://basketball.exposureevents.com/scripts/exposure.widgets.min.js";       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);   }   })(document, "script", "exp.widgets");</script>
```

Comment: How are you calling that action? Can you see the newlines when the action is hit?

Comment: Yes I can the newlines in the local variable called "text"

Comment: Are you sure the newlines are not being escaped in some way before then? I just created a test which is the same as your action, except with the variable 'text' hard-coded in the method body - I receive a file with newlines OK.

Comment: One other thing - how are you viewing the downloaded result? In Notepad++ the newlines will be evident, but if you open the result in notepad you will only get newlines for CRLF (\r\n).